# does babel provide a method of converting es6 import statements into AMD 'require' calls

Tags: javascript, requirejs, ecmascript-6, amd, babeljs

The Babel AMD module formatter works perfectly for modules, wrapping the script in a `define` statement. However, my project also has 'page scripts' that should execute as soon as dependencies are loaded. These should be wrapped in a `require` statement.

Does Babel provide a means of accomplishing this?

Comment: Yes and in fact it does that by default. See the documentation: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/modules/. Or maybe I misunderstand your question?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by "does that by default." if i use the AMD module formatter _all_ the js files i provide will be wrapped in define statements as modules. i need a way to specify that some of my scripts are not modules but need import statements transpiled to require() async calls.

I suspect this may require two separate passes with babel, with two different module formatter settings.

Comment: Then you have to compile those files separately with the CommonJS module formatter (which is the default module formatter).

Comment: @FelixKling unfortunately that doesn't work - commonjs uses require() synchronously. i need async usage.

Comment: How do you expect `var foo = require('./foo')` to work asynchronously? Or are you talking about a different `require` statement? It's not clear to me what you want, a code example would probably help. Or what you want is impossible.

Comment: @FelixKling The question here is tagged [tag:amd] and [tag:requirejs]. So, yes we are talking about a `require` which is different from the CommonJS one. RequireJS implements the AMD spec, which is wholly asynchronous. (Except for one syntactic sugar convenience which behaves synchronously after the module has already been loaded asynchronously.)

Comment: @Louis: Ah, all I saw was `define` in the docs, but now I see that there is `require([...], function() { ... })` as well.

Comment: Babel expects every file to be a module, so I guess there is no way to compile a file without using `define`. Your best bet may be to keep the page scripts small and only have the `require` calls in them. E.g. `require(['./foo'], function(foo) { foo.init(); });`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to get Babel to generate something like this:

```
require(['foo'], function (foo) {
   ... 
});
```

All the examples for AMD in the Babel documentation show Babel generating `define(...`. Moreover, there does not seem to be any clear way to indicate in ES6 that what *should* be generated by Babel is a `require` call instead of a `define` call. So the directive to Babel to output `require` would have to be extra-linguistic.

I've taken a look at the [source](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/16502488b966ee690ee45454d4c125c95f2ade8d/packages/babel/src/transformation/modules/amd.js) for the generation of AMD modules. I do not see any logic there that would cause Babel to output a `require` call, ever.

If I decided I needed a module translator that allows me to do this, I'd derive from [the class in this module](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/16502488b966ee690ee45454d4c125c95f2ade8d/packages/babel/src/transformation/modules/amd.js) a new class that would allow specifying that in some cases, a `require` call should be produced rather than `define`. I don't know Babel well enough to know whether it would be possible to prevent generating invalid creations (e.g. code in a `require` call that tries to `export` anything).

Otherwise, you can always call `require` like you used to.